# Java - Method implementation dependent from parameter value

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, methods

Consider a method

```
public void doSomething(String actionID){
switch (actionID){
    case "dance":
            System.out.print("I'm dancing");
            break;
    case "sleep":
            System.out.print("I'm sleeping");
            break;
    default: 
            System.out.print("I've no idea what I'm doing");
}
```

The implementation of the method depends on the value of the parameter. Is there a more elegant way to do this, or a different design pattern to replicate the behaviour?

Comment: Could be possible that you are looking for something like this? http://crunchify.com/why-and-for-what-should-i-use-enum-java-enum-examples/

Comment: You can implement a command pattern.

Answer (score 4):

If the caller decides what logic is executed by passing different strings, then why not just have them call different methods:

```
public void doSomething(String actionID) {...}
...
doSomething("dance");
doSomething("sleep");
```

VS.:

```
public void dance() {...}
public void sleep() {...}
...
dance();
sleep();
```

It seems like you're unnecessarily funnelling all the calls into `doSomething`

---

> But the strings might not always be literals. What if you're taking them from the console?

You could provide static mappings from the strings to the corresponding functions:

```
class MyClass {
    private static final Map<String, Consumer<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        map.put("sleep", MyClass::sleep);
        map.put("dance", MyClass::dance);
    }

    public void doSomething(String actionID) {
        map.getOrDefault(actionID, MyClass::doNothing).accept(this);
    }

    public void dance() {
        System.out.print("I'm dancing");
    }

    public void sleep() {
        System.out.print("I'm sleeping");
    }

    private void doNothing() {
        System.out.println("I've no idea what I'm doing");
    }
}
```

This makes scenarios where you have a lot of switch cases a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce an interface, e.g.

```
  public interface HumanState {

    public void tellMeWhatYouAreDoing();
  }
```

encapsulate the logic in different implementations

```
  public class DancingState implements HumanState {
    @Override
    public void tellMeWhatYouAreDoing() {
      System.out.println("I'm dancing");
    }
  }

  public class SleepingState implements HumanState {

    @Override
    public void tellMeWhatYouAreDoing() {
      System.out.println("I'm sleeping");
    }
  }

  public class UnknownState implements HumanState {

    @Override
    public void tellMeWhatYouAreDoing() {
      System.out.println("I've no idea what I'm doing");
    }
  }
```

and use a map. E.g.

```
public class HumanStateExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HumanStateExample humanStateExample = new HumanStateExample();

    humanStateExample.doSomething("dance");
    humanStateExample.doSomething("sleep");
    humanStateExample.doSomething("unknown");
  }

  private final HashMap<String, HumanState> humanStateMap;


  public HumanStateExample(){
    humanStateMap = new HashMap<String, HumanState>();
    humanStateMap.put("dance", new DancingState());
    humanStateMap.put("sleep", new SleepingState());

  }

  public void doSomething(String action) {
    HumanState humanState = humanStateMap.get(action);
    if(humanState == null){
      humanState = new UnknownState();
    }

    humanState.tellMeWhatYouAreDoing();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the pattern is called, but it is very useful if you need to delegate the method call based on more than one parameter:

Create a lot of handlers where each one knows when it is responsible for handling a call. Then just loop through them and invoke the first one matching the parameter.

*edit: I renamed the class from FancyParameterAction**Factory** to FancyParameterAction**Utility**: it is not a factory, the name was misleading*

```
//Your method, but this time with a complex object, not with a simple string.
public void doSomething(FancyParameterObject fpo){
    FancyParameterActionUtility.invokeOn(fpo);
}


 //The utility which can handle the complex object and decides what to do.
public class FancyParameterActionUtility{
    public Interface FPAHandler{
        void invoke(FancyParameterObject fpo);
        boolean handles(FancyParameterObject fpo);
    }

    //Omitted: Different implementations of FPAHandler

    public static List<FPAHandler> handlers = new LinkedList<>();

    static{
        handlers.add(new DanceHandler());
        handlers.add(new SleepHandler());
        //Omitted: Different implementations of FPAHandler
    }

    public static void invokeOn(FancyParameterObject fpo){
        for(FPAHandler handler:handlers){
            if (handler.handles(fpo)){
                handler.invoke(fpo);
                return;
            }
        }
        //Default-Behavior
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of the command pattern based your sample problem.  I define a general `AbstractCommand` abstract class which contains two methods.  The first method, `createCommand()`, instantiates a command class based on an input string name.  This is how you can delegate your string input to create the right type of command.  The second method is `doAction()`, and this is left undefined, to be implemented later on by specific concrete command classes.

```
public abstract class AbstractCommand {
    public static AbstractCommand createCommand(String name) {
        try {
            String clsName = name + "Command";
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(clsName);
            AbstractCommand command = (AbstractCommand) cls.newInstance();

            return command;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
        }
    }

    public abstract void doAction();
}

public class DanceCommand extends AbstractCommand {
    public void doAction() {
        System.out.println("I'm dancing");
    }
}

public class TestCommandPattern {
    public void doSomething(String actionID) {
        AbstractCommand cmd = AbstractCommand.createCommand(actionID);
        cmd.doAction();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCommandPattern test = new TestCommandPattern();
        test.doSomething("Dance");  // should print "I'm dancing"
    }
}
```

Now that this framework has been setup, you could easily add other commands for the various types of actions in your original problem.  For example, you could create a `SleepCommand` class which would output `I'm sleeping`, or do whatever action you wish.